# Cascading dropdown focused on specific value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, classic-experience, cascading-dropdown

I have a list A with column Country, and a column Cities.
I'm creating a library B with a column Cities, in which I want to see only the Cities only for a specific country, referring the values of my list A.
How can I tell my library B's column to do that ?
Best regards.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2016 (classic experience)? Check this: https://markrackley.net/2017/03/06/new-improved-cascading-dropdowns-for-sharepoint-classic-forms/. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I'm using classic experience.  I'll take a look at your link. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, let me know it it works for you.

Comment: Well this link shows how to create dropdowns at multilevel cascading, but it seems it does not answer to my need.  I want to pick the values from Cities only from a specific Country value in one dropdown column, not having a dropdown for both Cities and Countries. Or perhaps I should create those 2 dropdownlevels, hide one and specify the value of the hidden one (supposing the firstOptionText in the script can replace the value ouf Country) ?

Comment: You want to hardcode the country selection for single country value?

Comment: Well if it's the solution that can fit ...